# Button and image disappear Android

Tags: java, android

Im taking my first steps in developing for android. Following a tutorial i have created a button, textview,edit text, and am now trying to implimetn a list view.

i have followed the tutorial Exactly, and for some reason, when i implement the Tableview, my button and image disappear.

can anybody find out why?

.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    TextView mainTextView;
    Button mainButton;
    EditText mainEditText;
    ListView mainListView;
    ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter;
    ArrayList mNameList = new ArrayList();



    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //access the textview defined in Layout XML & set its value
        mainTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
        mainTextView.setText("set In Java!");
        //access the button defined in layout XML
        mainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);
        mainButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mainEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_edittext);
        mainListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_listview);
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mNameList);
        mainListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mainTextView.setText(mainEditText.getText().toString() + " is learning Android Development");
        mNameList.add(mainEditText.getText().toString());
        mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

activity.XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_textview"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textview"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/main_edittext"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/main_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- set OnClickListener to trigger results when pressed -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/button"/>
        <!--shows an image from your drawable rescources-->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: apply weight to edittext, textview and see

Comment: you are setting `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` to something in a parent which is set to wrap content. Simply put: How will the content adjust to parent when the parent is adjusting to the content.

developer.android.com would help you I think.

Comment: or you wont need weight to listview too. why weight to list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_textview"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textview"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/main_edittext"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/button"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/main_textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="textview" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/main_edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:hint="hint" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <!-- set OnClickListener to trigger results when pressed -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="button" />
        <!-- shows an image from your drawable rescources -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout` is horizontal by default.

Your `ListView` is `layout_width="match_parent"` and root `LinearLayout` is horizontal.
so ListView Expands wide, ImageView and etc have pushed out and become invisible.

I recommend you to always specify `android:orientation` (`"vertical"` or `"horizontal"`) in `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. i was just doing what the tutorial told me to do in the first instance - but your advice will be taken on board! Thanks again!